# How do we feel about placeholder answers to indicate we are working on an answer?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed on a few questions recently that several of us have hopped on to quickly answer a simple question.  We end up with several answers appearing in rapid succession that often have basically the same answer.  What do people think about submitting a placeholder answer like [I'm actively writing up an answer now] to indicate that others may not need to bother?

An example: someone asked the other day about how to sort some data in R, and three of us had extremely similar answers post within a couple minutes of each other.  Afterwards, we all just voted up the best explained version, and one answer's author commented that he wouldn't have posted his answer if he had seen that someone else was working on it.  I felt the same way.  There are names that I have learned to recognize in the R tag, and I don't feel the need to answer a straightforward question if one of those people are already writing something up.

Thoughts?  Ideas?

Comment: FSGITW (Fastest Shotgun in the West)

Comment: For some previous discussion, [here's a deal on Seasoned Advice](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/769/how-should-an-active-member-of-our-community-respond-to-placeholder-answers) that discussed the matter of placeholder answers.

Comment: Anyone want to document why the question is being downvoted, so I can know what is unclear or not useful?

Comment: Downvotes on meta are different from main. Here it means I don't like this idea, feature request / I don't agree @Dinre

Comment: @PeeHaa, Now that is very helpful.  Perhaps we should have a feature request to change the pop-up caption for the up-/down-vote on meta, so we meta-newbs can get acclimated faster.

Comment: @Dinre Oldest question I can find with that particular feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites

Comment: Dinre, you have some voting to do then: see [Automatically explain what downvotes on Meta mean](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110288/automatically-explain-what-downvotes-on-meta-mean), [Just in time help for Meta “Why downvotes?” comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136213/just-in-time-help-for-meta-why-downvotes-comments), [Make it even clearer that downvotes on Meta are different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132431/make-it-even-clearer-that-downvotes-on-meta-are-different), ...

Comment: Must...not...post...placeholder...answer...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Placeholders that don't contain any kind of actual answer are noise and are subject to deletion.  You can downvote them with confidence that you'll get your point back (either when the post is deleted, or when you remove your downvote after editing).  If people want to play FGITW, they need to at least post a TL;DR version of their actual answer as the first draft.

Comment: The idea of posting a brief answer and then fleshing it out is interesting.  I wonder how others feel about that.

Comment: @Dinre: I do it all the time. It's practically my lifeblood.

Comment: @Dinre, I dislike it, and it makes me not even try to answer very fresh new questions, knowing I'm just too slow. On the other hand that's okay to me, as it saves me time...! As an aside: sometimes placeholder answers [are converted into a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166372/answer-deleted-by-moderator-converted-to-comment-can-i-add-a-new-one/). I like that. Also, I like [Make first draft of a new answer part of the permanent revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history).

Comment: *You can downvote them with confidence that you'll get your point back.* - It might be nice if this were true (or it might not), but it's not factually true.  If the answer is currently blank because it's a placeholder, which  the answer is revising and the revised version will appear shortly, you're not going to automatically get your point back.  (You will have an opportunity to remove your downvote if you want to do so and remember to do so, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: @D.W. Either the post will be deleted or it will be edited. Either way, you can get your point back.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, you *can* get your point back is very different from you *will* get your point back.  You wrote the latter, but the reality is the former.

Comment: @D.W. If you care that much about it I assume you *will* get your point back.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a potentially useful feature with downsides. So many times I'm halfway through an answer, and have seen that someone has finished writing one up that kills it. I then don't even bother submitting mine. I guess the risk is that you don't answer a question because you see someone else is, and that answer eventually turns out to be useless. Meanwhile you've moved on to something else and the user is left hanging.

It's probable that Stack would rather see too many answers that cover all the bases, than too few just to avoid the risk of overlap.

Comment: You can surely assess the other users answer against your own. If yours is better/different/more comprehensive/about to be submitted submit anyway? Don't not submit a comprehensive answer because someone posted a tl;dr before you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this relates well to the question I was just asking: [Competitiveness of various tags on stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166653/competitiveness-of-various-tags-on-stackoverflow) in that this depends on your and others intents on answering the question.

On straight-forward questions in popular tags there always seems to be at least a few people looking to compete to answer quickly and score the reputation. I think in these cases you can assume an answer is coming and unless you are looking to *win* I would ignore them. In your situation I would only answer questions I knew to be tricky or were somewhat mature (30-60 minutes old?).

Comment: Personally, I really don't care about the reputation score on SO, but I do frequently hop onto basic questions in order to get the poster a quick result.  It's nice when you post a simple question and get an answer in minutes, so you can get on with your life.  Not caring about the rep, though, means I would ignore the question if someone else was actively writing up an answer.